# SQL Server 2017 Developer edition installation is stuck (hung up) endlessly

Tags: sql-server, installation, sql-server-2017

After overcoming [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47346445/465053) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47385969/465053) issue my hurdles don't seem to be coming to an end.

SQL Server 2017 Developer edition installation is going on endlessly. The installer isn't coming to an end and seems to have stuck on below step for last few days now:

- Install_MsMpi_Cpu64_Action

[image]

My task manager shows as below for this ongoing installation:

[image]

Here is what I saw through process explorer tool if that provides any clue:

[image]

**Operating System Info**: Windows 10

This machine is freshly built and there are no older installations of any previous versions of SQL Server on this machine. I chose to create a named SQL Server instance even though this is the first SQL Server instance on this machine. Can anyone help me with some pointers to go past this issue?

**Related post** - [SQL Server 2014 installation stuck (hung up) or taking very long time to finish](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40352574/465053)

Comment: Check the details tab to see if `ngen.exe` is what's consuming the CPU. If so, end that task and the installation should proceed.

Comment: I don't see any process name as `ngen.exe` in details tab.

Comment: @DanGuzman I've added a snapshot from process explorer tool if that gives you any ideas.

Comment: Click the details tab in task manager and order by CPU descending.

Comment: @DanGuzman There are in all 4 processes in `Details` tab starting with letter `n`. None of them `ngen.exe`. By any chance its display name could be anything else?

Answer (score 4):

Actual problem is Python Server; To add this feature it would take more time to download 850MB+ file, extract it and install the same;

Yes, I have successfully installed after 45 mins in time with the network :(

But after that I could see the "Installation is completed" Message.. :)

Comment: ref : https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/arvindsh/2017/08/11/sql-server-2017-setup-the-step-sql_inst_mpyconfigaction_upgrade_confignonrc_cpu64-seems-stuck-or-slow-heres-why/

Comment: ok. So to try your solution I'll try installing it again without selecting Python feature. I'll uncheck `Machine Learning Services(In-Database)` on feature selection screen of installation wizard. For now I don't intend to do any machine learning on the SQL instance. If needed I'll add this feature later. I'll share the details of this exercise with you in an hour or so.

Comment: I tried the setup after deselecting `Machine Learning Services(In-Database)` feature then also the issue is same. Interestingly, even after deselecting this feature the setup wizard still shows the terms and condition wizard step meant for Python and R both.

Comment: Thanks vaduganathan - I had the same issue and with some patience it went over the Python feature... is a pity that there is no warning of delay and people think the install is stuck!

Answer (score 0):

For now, I couldn't figure out any resolution of this particular solution after trying to figure out the root cause of hung up process for few days.

As an alternative path, I tried the same setup on a server operating system ( Windows Server 2012 R2) where I was able to install is successfully. I believe this issue is specific to client OSes like Windows 10 where I was trying earlier. I'm posting this info in case someone finds it useful even though this isn't a real solution.